# SQLite: update columns using group-by, count

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I'm using SQLite, and trying to figure out how to give discounts to the customers that they have made over 3 purchases recorded. I have tried the following but it only updates the discount of the first row of customer_ID  group by returns.

```
update orders
  set discount = price*0.5
where customer_ID = (
    select customer_ID from orders
    group by customer_ID
    having count(customer_ID) > 3
);
```

How can I implement the desired results described above?

Comment: `where customer_ID IN(...)` probably will help

Comment: If your subquery returns exacly the IDs of proper customers, it should be okay.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IN` instead of `=`.

`=` *means match exacly one result that equals to*

`IN` *means match all results that contained in list*

```
update orders
  set discount = price*0.5
where customer_ID IN (
    select customer_ID from orders
    group by customer_ID
    having count(customer_ID) > 3
);
```